# Backbone/Marionette routing - lacks depth

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I can post code if necessary, but my question seems generic.

I have three different BB routers running in a Marionette app.  The routers are all instantiated prior to calling Backbone.history.start().

On one of the routers, I have a route that takes a couple of parameters.  It works... I can always get to it.  However, when I navigate back, it'll only go back one page before it reverts back to the main screen.  Here's the hierarchy of screens:

```
Landing
   Search  
      Detail1
      Detail2
      Detail3
```

I can go from:

```
Landing->Search->Detail1->Detail2->Detail3.
```

Once I go back... this is what happens:

```
Detail3->Detail2->Search
```

Under NO circumstances do I ever get the option to nav forward again.

Happens in Chrome and Edge.

Does this sound familiar to anyone?  Root cause?

Answer (score 0):

So the problem ended up being the way the view was getting rendered.  Somewhere along the line, the entire view was getting wiped out to the "Search" level and that injected that route into the route history.  I refactored to be smarter about when to create the view (virgin request) versus merely updating it (nav back/forward) and now nav works as expected.